# How to execute one python file for a certain amount of time and after that, run another?

Tags: python, operating-system

I have two scripts; the first mines a bunch of data and the second analyses it. I want the first file to run for ~2 hours or so, and after that the second to just run once.

I understand that `os.system()` is not a very safe way to go about this. I would also like to understand why is that?

Perhaps, I should mention that the two python scripts need to be executed such that the main function gets invoked.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What operating system? You may be able to wire them together using python itself and not on the OS level (just import both in a top-level module).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows and are lazy you could create a batch job that does

```
python first_task.py
SLEEP 7200
python second_task.py
```